# How does one handle container directories on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am working on an app that saves files to the documents directory, and then saves an absolute path for each of those files in an entity using core data. The issue is that each time I rebuild and run my app on my device, the app is saved in a different generated directory, and those file paths are now incorrect. However, my documents directory is still preserved.

I have three questions about this:

1. If an app is updated on the store, does it then go in a different generated directory, thus invalidating any absolute paths that could be saved in the documents directory?
2. This is extremely unlikely but is there any way to specify in Xcode to build the app to the same directory the previous build was in?
3. Is there a way to specify in Xcode that you would like all documents and data wiped with each new build you load on the device?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do not to save the absolute paths, just the path inside the Documents directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

"I am working on an app that saves files to the documents directory, and then saves an absolute path for each of those files in an entity using core data."

Don't do that. Ever. The path to your documents directory will be different on different devices, and different if you delete your app and reinstall it. Absolute paths are pretty much guaranteed to fail.

Use paths relative to the sandbox directory in question (documents directory, temp directory, etc)